# C# syntax help, date formatting and adding " to strings

Tags: c#, ssis, formatting

This is my first foray into C# as a SSIS and Informatica developer living only in SQL.  I have a script task that is reading data from a single SQL Server table via Query and simply writing that data to a text file. Everything works except what I think are  two small formatting problems I can't figure out.

The following requirements are in place for this build.  Thanks in advance I'm here to answer any questions!

1. SQL query is purposefully set as a Select * to pick up any new columns added(already in code)
2. First 3 columns excluded from write to file(already in code)

Problems:

1. "  " wrappers need to be added to all values, column and rows.
2. Date in database is true Date but when writing to file it shows Datetime.  Needs to be only date.

Current:

| ID | Name | Date | Ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345678 | John Wayne | 12/31/2018 12:00:00 AM | 1/1 |

Needs to be:

| "ID" | "Name" | "Date" | "Ratio" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| "12345678" | "John Wayne" | "2018-12-31" | "1/1" |

Code:

```
// Declare Variables
string DestinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::Target_FilePath"].Value.ToString();
string QueryStage = Dts.Variables["User::Query_Stage"].Value.ToString();
//string TableName = Dts.Variables["User::TableName"].Value.ToString();
string FileName = Dts.Variables["User::OutputFileName"].Value.ToString();
string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::Target_FileDelim"].Value.ToString();
//string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::AC_Prefix"].Value.ToString();

//USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["ADO_TEST_CONN"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);

// Read data from table or view to data table
string query = QueryStage;

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
//myADONETConnection.Open();

DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
d_table.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
myADONETConnection.Close();

string FileFullPath = DestinationFolder + "\\" + FileName + ".txt";

StreamWriter sw = null;
sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

// Write the Header Row to File
int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;

for (int ic = 4; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
{
    sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);

    if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
    {
        sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
    }
}

sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

// Write All Rows to the File
foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
{
    for (int ir = 4; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
    {
        if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
        {
            sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
        }

        if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
        {
            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
        }
    }

    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
}

sw.Close();

Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
```

Comment: `sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());` If you don't detect that the value is a `DateTime`, and use the standard `ToString()`, that's what it's going to do.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response.  The datatype in the database is Date.  For some reason when writing to datatable or to the .txt file the time is getting added.

Answer (score 1):

Blindly running `.ToString()` on an `object`, which is done in the line `sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());`, is going to use the default settings of converting that data type into a string. If it's a `DateTime` (the c# data type, not the SQL `Date` column type), then it will include the time information.

C# converts SQL column types (such as `Date`) into C# data types (`DateTime`). You need to detect this, just as you're detecting if a value is DBNull.

```
if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
{
    if (dr[ir] is DateTime dt)
    {
        // use DateTime's specific string rendering
        sw.Write(dt.ToString("d"));
    }
    else
    {
        // fall back to standard string rendering
        sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
    }
}
```

You can change out the format (`"d"` in this case) to be [something else](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings) if you need a different format. Keep in mind that the Culture of a computer will affect how the string is rendered, unless you explicitly use a named Culture.

---

The other thing in your problem is adding quotes around printed values. This can be done with string concatination. For example:

```
string result = "\"" + "my string" + "\"";
// result is "my string", with quotes
```

Remember to escape the quote mark.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response.  I misrepresented the expeted date value displayed in the .txt file.  It needs to be 2018-12-31 instead of 12/31/2018.  I implemented your fix and i can indeed produce the date with no time on it.  I changed this to  dt.ToString("s") but and trying to trim somehow the time from this string.  Any ideas how to get the correct format of 2018-12-31?  In the meantime I am working to concat the quotes via your method.  Thanks!

Comment: The format would be `yyyy-MM-dd`. Read through the link in my post for more formats.

Comment: uhhh Duh....that was easy.  Working on the concatenation now.  THANKS!